# Find the probability that 8 students in a team will all have their birthday on exactly two days of the week (but not all in one day)?

Tags: probability

Having trouble understanding this question. Would the sample sample space be (7^8) where 7 days in a week with 8 team members?

Answer (score 2):

The sample space is the set of functions $$\{\text{team members}\} \to \{\text{days of the week}\}.$$ The domain and codomain have $8$ and $7$ elements respectively, so there are $7^8$ such functions.

Comment: Hey Travis, I'm wondering what is the $\Omega($8 people have all their birthdays on two days but not all in one day) = $C_{7,2} \cdot 8 * 8!$

Comment: Do you mean, what is the count of all such events? Let me suggest that you post that as a separate question.

Comment: Posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459277/how-many-arrangements-can-a-team-of-8-students-have-such-at-all-of-them-have-the, if you have time I'd appreciate it if you could enlighten me! Thank you